# Calculating Hessian matrix with nested gradient tape

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am attempting to calculate the Hessian matrix of the output of a neural network with respect to the input, using gradient tapes and 2 batch_jacobian functions. The first function returns the Jacobian, as expected, the second one returns a pretty meaningless error. The coordinates [:,0] in g are picked, since the Jacobian is calculated with respect to just one variable, hence the second axis only has length 1. The code does not execute past the point where the Hessian is calculated.

```
 def dynamics(self, x):  # compute guess of dynamics of the system, using current lagrangian model
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape2: # observing the first order derivatives
        tape2.watch(x)
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent = True) as tape:
            tape.watch(x)
            lagrangian = self.lagrangian_net(x)
            print(lagrangian)
        g = tape.batch_jacobian(lagrangian, x, unconnected_gradients='zero')[:, 0]
        print(g)
    hessian = tape2.batch_jacobian(g, x, unconnected_gradients='zero')
    print(hessian)
    U = g[:, 0, :] - tf.einsum("dij,dj->di", hessian[:, 1, :, 0, :], x[:, 1, :])  # U[d,i]
    P = hessian[:, 1, :, 1, :]
    P = tf.map_fn(tf.linalg.inv, P)  # P[d, i, k]
    A = tf.einsum("di,dik->dk", U, P)
    return A  # return accelerations for the batch
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py", line 1183, in batch_jacobian
> parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
> File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\parallel_for\control_flow_ops.py", line 164, in pfor
> return f()
> File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1323, in **call**
> graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1652, in _maybe_define_function
> graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1545, in _create_graph_function
> capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
> File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 715, in func_graph_from_py_func
> func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 705, in wrapper
> raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(type(e))
> ValueError: in converted code:
> relative to C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\parallel_for:

```
control_flow_ops.py:161 f *
    return _pfor_impl(loop_fn, iters, parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
control_flow_ops.py:214 _pfor_impl
    outputs.append(converter.convert(loop_fn_output))
pfor.py:1175 convert
    output = self._convert_helper(y)
pfor.py:1343 _convert_helper
    "which may run slower" % (y_op.type, y_op, converted_inputs))

ValueError: No converter defined for PartitionedCall
name: "loop_body/PartitionedCall"
op: "PartitionedCall"
input: "loop_body/Reshape_4"
input: "loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_1"
input: "loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_2"
input: "loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_3"
input: "loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_4"
input: "loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_5"
attr {
  key: "Tin"
  value {
    list {
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_INT32
    }
  }
}
attr {
  key: "Tout"
  value {
    list {
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_DOUBLE
    }
  }
}
attr {
  key: "_gradient_op_type"
  value {
    s: "PartitionedCall-385"
  }
}
attr {
  key: "config"
  value {
    s: ""
  }
}
attr {
  key: "config_proto"
  value {
    s: "\n\007\n\003CPU\020\001\n\007\n\003GPU\020\0002\002J\0008\001"
  }
}
attr {
  key: "executor_type"
  value {
    s: ""
  }
}
attr {
  key: "f"
  value {
    func {
      name: "__inference___backward_f_232_270"
    }
  }
}

inputs: [WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/Reshape_4/pfor/Reshape:0' shape=(4, 1, 3, 2, 2) dtype=float64>, is_stacked=True, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_1:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float64>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_2:0' shape=(3, 1) dtype=float64>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_3:0' shape=(1, 3, 1) dtype=float64>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_4:0' shape=(1, 3, 1) dtype=float64>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_5:0' shape=(3,) dtype=int32>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False)]. 
Either add a converter or set --op_conversion_fallback_to_while_loop=True, which may run slower
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Maks/Desktop/neural/lagrangian neural network.py", line 129, in 
N.train(2)
File "C:/Users/Maks/Desktop/neural/lagrangian neural network.py", line 110, in train
self.train_step(x, true_y)
File "C:/Users/Maks/Desktop/neural/lagrangian neural network.py", line 98, in train_step
acc = self.dynamics(x)
File "C:/Users/Maks/Desktop/neural/lagrangian neural network.py", line 83, in dynamics
hessian = tape2.batch_jacobian(g, x, unconnected_gradients='zero')
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py", line 1191, in batch_jacobian
sys.exc_info()[2])
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 702, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py", line 1183, in batch_jacobian
parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\parallel_for\control_flow_ops.py", line 164, in pfor
return f()
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1323, in **call**
graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1652, in _maybe_define_function
graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1545, in _create_graph_function
capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 715, in func_graph_from_py_func
func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 705, in wrapper
raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(type(e))
ValueError: in converted code:
relative to C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\parallel_for:

```
control_flow_ops.py:161 f *
    return _pfor_impl(loop_fn, iters, parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
control_flow_ops.py:214 _pfor_impl
    outputs.append(converter.convert(loop_fn_output))
pfor.py:1175 convert
    output = self._convert_helper(y)
pfor.py:1343 _convert_helper
    "which may run slower" % (y_op.type, y_op, converted_inputs))

ValueError: No converter defined for PartitionedCall
name: "loop_body/PartitionedCall"
op: "PartitionedCall"
input: "loop_body/Reshape_4"
input: "loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_1"
input: "loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_2"
input: "loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_3"
input: "loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_4"
input: "loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_5"
attr {
  key: "Tin"
  value {
    list {
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_INT32
    }
  }
}
attr {
  key: "Tout"
  value {
    list {
      type: DT_DOUBLE
      type: DT_DOUBLE
    }
  }
}
attr {
  key: "_gradient_op_type"
  value {
    s: "PartitionedCall-385"
  }
}
attr {
  key: "config"
  value {
    s: ""
  }
}
attr {
  key: "config_proto"
  value {
    s: "\n\007\n\003CPU\020\001\n\007\n\003GPU\020\0002\002J\0008\001"
  }
}
attr {
  key: "executor_type"
  value {
    s: ""
  }
}
attr {
  key: "f"
  value {
    func {
      name: "__inference___backward_f_232_270"
    }
  }
}

inputs: [WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/Reshape_4/pfor/Reshape:0' shape=(4, 1, 3, 2, 2) dtype=float64>, is_stacked=True, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_1:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float64>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_2:0' shape=(3, 1) dtype=float64>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_3:0' shape=(1, 3, 1) dtype=float64>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_4:0' shape=(1, 3, 1) dtype=float64>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/PartitionedCall/args_5:0' shape=(3,) dtype=int32>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False)]. 
Either add a converter or set --op_conversion_fallback_to_while_loop=True, which may run slower
```

Encountered an exception while vectorizing the batch_jacobian computation. Vectorization can be disabled by setting experimental_use_pfor to False.
Exception ignored in: <function _EagerDefinedFunctionDeleter.**del** at 0x0000026FE02C50D8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 305, in **del**
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 1663, in remove_function
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 865, in remove_function
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception ignored in: <function _EagerDefinedFunctionDeleter.**del** at 0x0000026FE02C50D8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 305, in **del**
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 1663, in remove_function
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 865, in remove_function
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception ignored in: <function _EagerDefinedFunctionDeleter.**del** at 0x0000026FE02C50D8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 305, in **del**
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 1663, in remove_function
File "C:\Users\Maks\Anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 865, in remove_function
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

Solved by updating to tensorflow 2.1